# In login or signup form, after I click on login or signup, I must reload before it detects a token in localStorage and then it redirects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using redux to keep track of the user's state and handle any actions to be performed via backend. Once a user enters their information, it dispatches the login action creator with the user data and history for redirecting.

Login.js (Signup.js is similar as well)

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { 
    Container, 
    Typography, 
    Button, 
    TextField,
    Dialog,
    DialogActions,
    DialogContent,
    DialogContentText,
    DialogTitle, 
    CircularProgress
} from '@material-ui/core';
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
import * as yup from 'yup';
import { PASSWORD_REGEX, EMAIL_REGEX } from "../../validators/form-validation";

import useStyles from "./styles";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { login } from '../../redux';

// validation schema
const validationSchema = yup.object({
    email: yup
        .string('Enter your email.')
        .email('Enter a valid email.')
        .matches(EMAIL_REGEX, "Invalid email.")
        .required('Email is required.'),
    password: yup
        .string('Enter your password')
        .min(6, 'Password should be of minimum 6 characters length.')
        .matches(PASSWORD_REGEX, "Invalid password. Must be alphanumeric.")
        .required('Password is required.'),
});

function Login() {

    const classes = useStyles();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const history = useHistory();
    const [errorModal, setErrorModal] = useState(false);
    const state = useSelector(state => state.users);

    const openModal = () => {
        setErrorModal(true);
    };

    const closeModal = () => {
        setErrorModal(false);
    };

    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            email: '',
            password: ''
        },
        validationSchema: validationSchema,
        onSubmit: (userData) => {
            dispatch(login(userData, history));
        }
    });

    if (state.loading) {
        return <CircularProgress />
    }

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Container className={classes.container} maxWidth="sm">
                <Typography
                    variant="h4"
                    className={classes.header}
                >
                    LOGIN
                </Typography>
                <form 
                    className={classes.form} 
                    onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}
                >
                    <Typography
                        className={classes.label}
                        variant="body2"
                    >
                        Email
                    </Typography>
                    <TextField 
                        name="email"
                        type="email"
                        className={classes.textbox}
                        variant="outlined"
                        label="Enter Email"
                        value={formik.values.email}
                        onChange={formik.handleChange}
                        error={formik.touched.email && !!(formik.errors.email)}
                        helperText={formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email}
                        fullWidth
                    />
                    <Typography
                        className={classes.label}
                        variant="body2"
                    >
                        Password
                    </Typography>
                    <TextField 
                        className={classes.textbox}
                        name="password"
                        type="password"
                        variant="outlined"
                        label="Enter Password"
                        fullWidth
                        value={formik.values.password}
                        onChange={formik.handleChange}
                        error={formik.touched.password && !!(formik.errors.password)}
                        helperText={formik.touched.password && formik.errors.password}
                    />
                    <Button
                        className={classes.buttonSubmit}
                        variant="contained"
                        color="primary"
                        type="submit"
                        size="large"
                        fullWidth                    
                    >
                        LOGIN
                    </Button>
                    <Typography
                        variant="subtitle2"
                    >
                        {"Don't have an account? Click "}
                        <Link
                            to="/signup"
                        >
                            here
                        </Link>
                        {" to sign up!"}
                    </Typography>
                </form>
            </Container>
            <Dialog
                open={errorModal}
                onClose={closeModal}
            >
                <DialogTitle>
                    Login Error
                </DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                    <DialogContentText>
                        {state.error}
                    </DialogContentText>
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                    <Button onClick={closeModal} color="primary">
                        OKAY
                    </Button>
                </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default Login;
```

login action

```
import {
    LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    LOGIN_REQUEST,
    LOGIN_FAILURE,
    SIGNUP_REQUEST,
    SIGNUP_SUCCESS,
    SIGNUP_FAILURE,
    LOGOUT,
} from "./usersConstants";
import * as api from "../../api/users";

export const login = (user, history) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            dispatch({
                type: LOGIN_REQUEST,
            });
            const { data } = await api.login(user);
            dispatch({
                type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
                payload: data.user
            });
            history.push("/home");
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch({
                type: LOGIN_FAILURE,
                payload: error.message
            });
        }
    };
};
```

usersReducer.js

```
import {
    LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    LOGIN_REQUEST,
    LOGIN_FAILURE,
    SIGNUP_REQUEST,
    SIGNUP_SUCCESS,
    SIGNUP_FAILURE,
    LOGOUT
} from "./usersConstants";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    loading: false,
    error: '',
    token: null,
    userId: null
};

export const usersReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOGIN_REQUEST: {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            }
        }
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS: {
            localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(
                {
                    userId: action.payload.userId,
                    token: action.payload.token,
                }
            ));
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                token: action.payload.token,
                userId: action.payload.userId,
                error: ''
            }
        }
        case LOGIN_FAILURE: {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                token: null,
                userId: null,
                error: action.payload
            }
        }
        case SIGNUP_REQUEST: {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
            }
        }
        case SIGNUP_SUCCESS: {
            localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(
                {
                    userId: action.payload.userId,
                    token: action.payload.token,
                }
            ));
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                token: action.payload.token,
                userId: action.payload.userId,
                error: ''
            }
        }
        case SIGNUP_FAILURE: {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                token: null,
                userId: null,
                error: action.payload
            }
        }
        case LOGOUT: {
            localStorage.removeItem("userData");
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                token: null,
                userId: null,
                error: ''
            }
        }
        default: return state;
    }
};
```

If there dispatches LOGIN_SUCCESS, then I store the token received into localStorage. I have double checked and the data is reflected there as well. As well as in the logs, it does show LOGIN_REQUEST followed as LOGIN_SUCCESS and the payload is reflected as well.

In my App.js, I have predefined routes for if a user is logged in or not, checked via a token in the localStorage. However, it seems that the state isn't reflected right away (not checking the latest state of users) and thus can't login after the login button is clicked, but instead I have to reload. Same thing goes for when an error comes back from the backend and I want to display it, I still have to click the login button again for it to do so. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: I don’t have an exact solution to your setup. But I would suggest keeping the side effects (redirection) outside of actions as they should be as pure as possible. I would just use the push (from history) within the component. Then trigger the push off of the click handler. If you need to verify the store mutation then connect some selectors pointing to the store and trigger the push with useEffect and those selectors in the dependency array. You can set up a code sand box if you want me to test it out

Comment: I think I've tried using useSelector and including the state as a variable as part of useEffect but it didn't work (most likely because I misunderstood something on my end). Here is a code sand box link 

https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-drake-9uejg?file=/src/components/Navbar/Navbar.js

Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: I couldn't get passed your api calls so I made a hack around it. But I got it working for the most part https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-feistel-b8z3u . The problem was mostly your routes should be put into state and wrapped with useEffect, otherwise the app will likely render and miss your condition. I also left a comment about relying on store only and not using localStorage

Comment: I understand now. Thank you very much @ColinRosati for your help, and the comment was super helpful as well.